# Flask werkzeug log outputs weird characters by default

Tags: python, flask, logging, werkzeug

The log output looks something like this (plus a couple of unprintable characters, depending on editor?)

```
"[37mPOST /return HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
```

Is this intentional or broken?

Answer (score 0):

This should be a code color but it depends on your terminal, and it may not display correctly (your case).

You can find more information here: [Colorize Terminal Output in Python](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/colorize-terminal-output-python)